# On the nature of (magnetic) force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, quantum-electrodynamics

Imagine a metal object attached to an electromagnet that would otherwise fall to Earth. Does the magnetic field do work in resisting the fall? If so what are the force carriers? Indeed what are the force carriers in the (relativistically related) phenomena of electric attraction and repulsion? Obviously not photons!

Now if it did do work I suppose that could accounted for in the heat created by the circulation of the current in the wires. But what about a static magnet? It has no source of energy so presumably does no work but then neither can the electromagnet.

Apologies if these sound more metaphysical than physical - I hope not though. I have a physics (astrophysics really) degree but not at all clear about the answers - this is what covid-19 lockdowns do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look up the definition of [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) in physics. At this level, it usually includes displacement.

> metal object attached to an electromagnet that would otherwise fall to Earth

No displacement - no work.

As far as force carriers are concerned... Do you actually need this? The question is perfectly answerable within classical mechanics/electrodynamics, and the answer is easy. Force is 'carried' by the electromagnetic field. If you start diving into quantum field theory the force will still be carried by the electromagnetic field, but now you will need to quantize the field (and you will get photons).

Comment: Going to accept this and ask some more questions later - but I don't think "classical theory works so don't bother" is a good explanation!

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin. It is up to you of course, but if I wanted to know about quantum mechanical treatment of magnetic force I would ask "under which circumstances does classical description give incorrect results?". Very often trying to get quantum description "no matter what" ends up being a protracted bu futile excersize - you get classical behaviour but with much more complex math.

Comment: I am familiar with quantum optics, rather than quantization of magnetostatic field. Now, in QO, the quantum behaviour often manifests itself in second and higher order corellations. So maybe this is what you should be looking at? I.e. ask the question what is the corellation of magnetic field strength around a permananet magnet (for the case of magnet being in thermal state, pure state, superposition, entangled state) etc.